# Sección Negocios redirecciona a la página de StackOverflowBusiness (en inglés)

Tags: soporte, traducciones

En la sección **`ayuda --> Negocios`** te redirecciona a la página https://www.stackoverflowbusiness.com/?ref=topbar_help la cuál está completamente en inglés porque pertenece a http://StackOverflow.com

Tengo entendido que por el momento no existe como tal un modelo de negocios aplicable a Stack Overflow en español, pero sería ideal tener una de las siguientes 3 opciones:

- El contenido de esa página en un link como https://www.es.stackoverflowbusiness.com/?ref=topbar_help el cual contenga la misma información en español.
- Una página en un link como https://www.es.stackoverflowbusiness.com/?ref=topbar_help que tenga cierta descripción que próximanente estará disponible, en caso de que el modelo aplique a futuro.
- Si el modelo de negocios no será aplicable a Stack Overflow en español, quitar esa opción del menú `ayuda`.

Comment: ¿Te estas ofreciendo a traducirla? :)

Comment: @Rubén sí claro :) siempre y cuando la opción 1 o 2 sea la elegida :)

Comment: Me temo que no veremos cambios pronto. Ojalá me equivoque.